# Add custom filed for video selector in Sitefinity

Tags: video, telerik, custom-fields, sitefinity

We need to add custom filed for video selector in Sitefinity ,We tried using  “custom filed for news” 
Using following steps
•   Add a filed
•   Type- Long text
•   Name- video
•   Interface widget for entering data – custom
•   Type or Virtual path of the custom widget - Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI.Fields.VideoField.VideoSelector

But showing error "Type "Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI.Fields.VideoField.VideoSelector" cannot be resolved." at the time of creating this filed.

Answer (score 1):

I think in versions 7+ you can easily add a media field (e.g. video, images, etc.) to any content type (news, blogs, etc.) out of the box.